# Developer log in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Does Joomla have a general purpose API for logging debug information to a file, or to the database, so that extension writers can capture debug info from a live site?

Enabling debug output and logging to screen is not an option. It's a live site.

Something like Drupal's watchdog would be nice.

Comment: There is a JLog class and you can find more details here - 
https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/logging-to-a-file-only-with-jlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for the short answer :)

This page might help: https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog

It shows how to configure the log output and how to use logging in your own code.

---

EDIT, in case the link dies:
Enable "Log Everything" under the properties of the System - Debug plugin.
To create log records:

```
JLog::add("Hello world", JLog::INFO);
```

If within a namespace, qualify JLog:

```
\JLog::add("Hello world", \JLog::INFO);
```

There's no built-in log reading UI, just look at `administrator/logs/everything.php`.

Comment: On Joomla 3.9.28 on PHP 7.3.2, JLog::add causes an out of memory error on an otherwise not particularly memory hungry script.